# Need some guidance for this simple WPF single window load page

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to get up to speed with some intermediate things in WPF and I'm building this small application as my learning grounds.

I have a collection of five pictures. Each picture has certain data tied to it: owner, date, size, etc.

I'd like to be able to click that picture and load that information into display in the same window. I do NOT want to load the information in a new opened window.

Any suggestions on what to search for, or even a small verbal walk through of the process?

I'm using a `Frame` to load the initial five picture, but I don't know how to capture the click on the main parent window if the click is being registered inside the user control.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="22" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="_File" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit" />
        <MenuItem Header="_View" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Help" />
    </Menu>
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Name="contentFrame" Source="Roster.xaml" />
</Grid>
```

Then in Roster.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OracleOfLegends.Roster"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    //Lots of goodies here.
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do pretty much the same thing in WPF using a [`Frame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx) which you can navigate to a new `UserControl` containing the information.

Answer (score 1):

You never mentioned about you Model Object ... so i will assume it as

## Model

```
public class MyPicture : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string url;
    private string name;
    // Other fields

   public Url
   {
            get{ return value;}
            set{url=value;}
            OnPropertyChanged("Url")
   }
}
    //Do same for other fields . I leave the implementation if INPC on you
```

## ViewModel MyPictureListViewModel

```
    public MyPictureListViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
            ObservableCollection<MyPictureList> picList;
            public PicList
            {
                    get{return value;}
                    set{piclist=value;}
                    OnPropertyChanged("PicList")
            }
            //Fill the list with some methods... it depends on you
    }

/// <summary>
///   Interaction logic for MyUserControl.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class PicListDisplay
{
    private readonly MyPictureListViewModel
        myPictureListViewModel;

    /// <summary>
    ///   PicListDisplay
    /// </summary>
    public PicListDisplay()
    {
        myPictureListViewModel= new MyPictureListViewModel();
        this.DataContext = myPictureListViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

            I would prefer to use ListView
       <ListView Name="myPicListView" ItemsSource={Binding PicList}>
                  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <Datatemplate>
                                                   <UserControls:Roster/>           
                                        </DataTemplate>
                  </ListView.ItemTemplate>

       </ListView> 
                  // Here i am just Displaying the name you can put any control you want
        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,Elementname=myPicListView}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>            </UserControl>
```

Here i have made a listView and then on selecting the listview you can get the Data On the same window.... also you can create you Own view  like that of Windows Explorer or else and use inside a list View